# logcat error can't find the error

Tags: java, android

**This is my main activity, this is the code for camera filter. I didn't figure it out any error. but when i run this code it is crashing in my real device.can any one help in this please where is the error and what is error belongs to. I am attaching the log cat error as a pic. please find it**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERSIMMISON = 101;
    private CameraRenderer renderer;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private int filterId = R.id.filter0;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Original");

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager
                .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera acess is required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERSIMMISON);
            }


        } else {
            setupCameraPreviewView();
        }

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    void setupCameraPreviewView() {
        renderer = new CameraRenderer(this);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(renderer);
        textureView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        renderer.setSelectedFilter(R.id.filter0);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        renderer.setSelectedFilter(filterId);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        textureView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                renderer.onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(null, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        filterId = item.getItemId();
        if (filterId == R.id.capture) {
            Toast.makeText(this, capture() ? "The capture has been saved to your sdcard root path." : "Saved failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        setTitle(item.getTitle());

        if (renderer != null)
            renderer.setSelectedFilter(filterId);
        return true;
    }


    private boolean capture() {
        String mPath = genSaveFileName(getTitle().toString() + "_", ".png");
        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            imageFile.delete();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = textureView.getBitmap();
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String genSaveFileName(String prefix, String suffix) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
        String timeString = dateFormat1.format(date);
        String externalPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        return externalPath + "/" + prefix + timeString + suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://giri.com.camerafilter/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://giri.com.camerafilter/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}







<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my CameraRenderer.java**

```
public class CameraRenderer extends Thread implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraRenderer";
    private static final int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;
    private static final int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
    private static final int DRAW_INTERVAL = 1000 / 30;

    private Context context;
    private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
    private int gwidth, gheight;

    private EGLDisplay eglDisplay;
    private EGLSurface eglSurface;
    private EGLContext eglContext;
    private EGL10 egl10;

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceTexture cameraSurfaceTexture;
    private int cameraTextureId;
    private CameraFilter selectedFilter;
    private SparseArray<CameraFilter> cameraFilterMap = new SparseArray<>();

    public CameraRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, gwidth = width, gheight = height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        }
        interrupt();
        CameraFilter.release();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        if (isAlive()) {
            interrupt();
        }

        surfaceTexture = surface;
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, gwidth = width, gheight = height);

        // Open camera
        Pair<Camera.CameraInfo, Integer> backCamera = getBackCamera();
        final int backCameraId = backCamera.second;
        camera = Camera.open(backCameraId);

        // Start rendering
        start();
    }

    public void setSelectedFilter(int id) {
        selectedFilter = cameraFilterMap.get(id);
        selectedFilter.onAttach();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        initGL(surfaceTexture);

        // Setup camera filters map
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter0, new OriginalFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter1, new EdgeDetectionFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter2, new PixelizeFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter3, new EMInterferenceFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter4, new TrianglesMosaicFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter5, new LegofiedFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter6, new TileMosaicFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter7, new BlueorangeFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter8, new ChromaticAberrationFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter9, new BasicDeformFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter10, new ContrastFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter11, new NoiseWarpFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter12, new RefractionFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter13, new MappingFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter14, new CrosshatchFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter15, new LichtensteinEsqueFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter16, new AsciiArtFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter17, new MoneyFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter18, new CrackedFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter19, new PolygonizationFilter(context));
        cameraFilterMap.append(R.id.filter20, new JFAVoronoiFilter(context));
        setSelectedFilter(R.id.filter0);

        // Create texture for camera preview
        cameraTextureId = MyGLUtils.genTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
        cameraSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(cameraTextureId);

        // Start camera preview
        try {
            camera.setPreviewTexture(cameraSurfaceTexture);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Something bad happened
        }

        // Render loop
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                // Update the camera preview texture
                synchronized (this) {
                    cameraSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
                }

                // Draw camera preview
                selectedFilter.draw(cameraTextureId, gwidth, gheight);

                // Flush
                GLES20.glFlush();
                egl10.eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);

                Thread.sleep(DRAW_INTERVAL);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        cameraSurfaceTexture.release();
        GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, new int[]{cameraTextureId}, 0);
    }

    private void initGL(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        egl10 = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();

        eglDisplay = egl10.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        if (eglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglGetDisplay failed " + android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
        }

        int[] version = new int[2];
        if (!egl10.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglInitialize failed " + android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
        }

        int[] configsCount = new int[1];
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
        int[] configSpec = {
                EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,
                EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
                EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };

        EGLConfig eglConfig = null;
        if (!egl10.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configSpec, configs, 1, configsCount)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("eglChooseConfig failed " + android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
        } else if (configsCount[0] > 0) {
            eglConfig = configs[0];
        }
        if (eglConfig == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglConfig not initialized");
        }

        int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE};
        eglContext = egl10.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
        eglSurface = egl10.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, texture, null);

        if (eglSurface == null || eglSurface == EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
            int error = egl10.eglGetError();
            if (error == EGL10.EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW) {
                Log.e(TAG, "eglCreateWindowSurface returned EGL10.EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW");
                return;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("eglCreateWindowSurface failed " + android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(error));
        }

        if (!egl10.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed " + android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
        }
    }

    private Pair<Camera.CameraInfo, Integer> getBackCamera() {
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        final int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; ++i) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                return new Pair<>(cameraInfo, i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

**This is my CameraFilter.java file**

public abstract class CameraFilter {
    static final float SQUARE_COORDS[] = {
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    static final float TEXTURE_COORDS[] = {
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    static FloatBuffer VERTEX_BUF, TEXTURE_COORD_BUF;
    static int PROGRAM = 0;

    private static final int BUF_ACTIVE_TEX_UNIT = GLES20.GL_TEXTURE8;
    private static RenderBuffer CAMERA_RENDER_BUF;

    private static final float ROATED_TEXTURE_COORDS[] = {
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    private static FloatBuffer ROATED_TEXTURE_COORD_BUF;

    final long START_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int iFrame = 0;

    public CameraFilter(Context context) {
        // Setup default Buffers
        if (VERTEX_BUF == null) {
            VERTEX_BUF = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SQUARE_COORDS.length * 4)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            VERTEX_BUF.put(SQUARE_COORDS);
            VERTEX_BUF.position(0);
        }

        if (TEXTURE_COORD_BUF == null) {
            TEXTURE_COORD_BUF = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEXTURE_COORDS.length * 4)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            TEXTURE_COORD_BUF.put(TEXTURE_COORDS);
            TEXTURE_COORD_BUF.position(0);
        }

        if (ROATED_TEXTURE_COORD_BUF == null) {
            ROATED_TEXTURE_COORD_BUF = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ROATED_TEXTURE_COORDS.length * 4)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            ROATED_TEXTURE_COORD_BUF.put(ROATED_TEXTURE_COORDS);
            ROATED_TEXTURE_COORD_BUF.position(0);
        }

        if (PROGRAM == 0) {
            PROGRAM = MyGLUtils.buildProgram(context, R.raw.vertext, R.raw.original_rtt);
        }
    }

    @CallSuper
    public void onAttach() {
        iFrame = 0;
    }

    final public void draw(int cameraTexId, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight) {
        // TODO move?
        // Create camera render buffer
        if (CAMERA_RENDER_BUF == null ||
                CAMERA_RENDER_BUF.getWidth() != canvasWidth ||
                CAMERA_RENDER_BUF.getHeight() != canvasHeight) {
            CAMERA_RENDER_BUF = new RenderBuffer(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, BUF_ACTIVE_TEX_UNIT);
        }

        // Use shaders
        GLES20.glUseProgram(PROGRAM);

        int iChannel0Location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(PROGRAM, "iChannel0");
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, cameraTexId);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(iChannel0Location, 0);

        int vPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(PROGRAM, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLocation);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, VERTEX_BUF);

        int vTexCoordLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(PROGRAM, "vTexCoord");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoordLocation);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vTexCoordLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, ROATED_TEXTURE_COORD_BUF);

        // Render to texture
        CAMERA_RENDER_BUF.bind();
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        CAMERA_RENDER_BUF.unbind();
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        onDraw(CAMERA_RENDER_BUF.getTexId(), canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        iFrame ++;
    }

    abstract void onDraw(int cameraTexId, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight);

    void setupShaderInputs(int program, int[] iResolution, int[] iChannels, int[][] iChannelResolutions) {
        setupShaderInputs(program, VERTEX_BUF, TEXTURE_COORD_BUF, iResolution, iChannels, iChannelResolutions);
    }

    void setupShaderInputs(int program, FloatBuffer vertex, FloatBuffer textureCoord, int[] iResolution, int[] iChannels, int[][] iChannelResolutions) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

        int iResolutionLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "iResolution");
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(iResolutionLocation, 1,
                FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{(float) iResolution[0], (float) iResolution[1], 1.0f}));

        float time = ((float) (System.currentTimeMillis() - START_TIME)) / 1000.0f;
        int iGlobalTimeLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "iGlobalTime");
        GLES20.glUniform1f(iGlobalTimeLocation, time);

        int iFrameLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "iFrame");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(iFrameLocation, iFrame);

        int vPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLocation);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, vertex);

        int vTexCoordLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vTexCoord");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoordLocation);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vTexCoordLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, textureCoord);

        for (int i = 0; i < iChannels.length; i ++) {
            int sTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "iChannel" + i);
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, iChannels[i]);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(sTextureLocation, i);
        }

        float _iChannelResolutions[] = new float[iChannelResolutions.length * 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < iChannelResolutions.length; i++) {
            _iChannelResolutions[i*3] = iChannelResolutions[i][0];
            _iChannelResolutions[i*3 + 1] = iChannelResolutions[i][1];
            _iChannelResolutions[i*3 + 2] = 1.0f;
        }

        int iChannelResolutionLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "iChannelResolution");
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(iChannelResolutionLocation,
                _iChannelResolutions.length, FloatBuffer.wrap(_iChannelResolutions));
    }

    public static void release() {
        PROGRAM = 0;
        CAMERA_RENDER_BUF = null;
    }
}
```

**Still getting an error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1759 Process: giri.com.camerafilter, PID: 21244
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void giri.com.camerafilter.RenderBuffer.unbind()' on a null object reference
at giri.com.camerafilter.filter.CameraFilter.draw(CameraFilter.java:126)
at giri.com.camerafilter.CameraRenderer.run(CameraRenderer.java:165)
```

Comment: Post your FULL logcat here

Comment: i have been added please find it @shaishav

Comment: Don't use image for logcat. Copy the text and post it here. The crucial info is getting cut in both images

Comment: i Have add logcat

Comment: Can you share your xml for the activity?

Comment: @Shaishav i have added please check it

Comment: Please copy and paste the logcat here instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: "at giri.com.camerafilter.filter.CameraFilter.draw(CameraFilter.java:126)" What is line 126 of `CameraFilter.java`?

Comment: @code-Apprentice i have added the logcat as you said. i have copied and pasted it on the bottom of the page

NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void giri.com.camerafilter.RenderBuffer.unbind()' on a null object reference at

Comment: @MaheshBabu The logcat you pasted is different than the ones in the screenshots. Are you getting a different error now? If so, you should post a new question.

Comment: CAMERA_RENDER_BUF.unbind(); this is the line for camefilter.126
selectedFilter.draw(cameraTextureId, gwidth, gheight); this is for  CameraRenderer.java:165

Comment: @code-apprentice: this is the another error. could you please help me

Comment: @MaheshBabu I'll be glad to if/when I have time. Please post a new question so other's here at Stack Overflow can help you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `ClassCastException` because you're trying to cast a `TextView` to `TextureView`.Change:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

to `<TextureView...>`:

```
<TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Comment: Still im getting this error. i have adding now. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

There is `classCastException` which states that You are `casting` one `class` to another `class` which have different signatures. You have used `AppCompatTextview` in your xml and You are Casting it to `TextView`

you might be doing this

```
AppCompatTextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

and you should do as follows

```
AppCompatTextView textView = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

Comment: @MaheshBabu just clean and build app once. If error still persists then check if you have added support library compilation in gradle

Comment: @MaheshBabu are you able to import AppCompatTextView? If not use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` to import

Comment: i have imported and i have been added libraries. still gets the same error

Comment: Make sure you use AppCompatTextView instead of AppCompatTextview

Comment: Thanks @indramurari